# ruby "gem not found" error after updating older gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rack

updated rack from 2.2.7 to 3.0.8 now I'm getting the following error after running bundle install:

```
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems.rb:265:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem rack (>= 0.a) with executable rackup (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems.rb:284:in `activate_bin_path'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/rackup:25:in `<main>'
```

the error started when the gem rack-session apparently was requiring an newer version or rack:

```
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:155:in `<class:Cookie>': undefined method `DelegateClass' for Rack::Session::Cookie:Class
```

so I updated it to the latest version, and removed the older version of rack, now I'm getting the error, what do I do?

Comment: How did you update? A project's Gemfile managed by Bundler should handle dependency resolutions. If you're doing it by hand, you're largely on your own.

Comment: updated forcing it, but looking at other gem's specification, was required rack > 0.4, and rack >=3.0, so don't seens to have any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rackup executable was extracted from rack to the separate [`rackup`](https://github.com/rack/rackup) gem since rack 3.0.0. Thus, to use the `rackup` command with rack >= 3.0, you also have to add

```
gem "rackup"
```

to your `Gemfile`.

Comment: initially I had to make some adjustments to bound the new rack 3.0 changes with my old application, but it worked, ty